# error while updating a pass

Tags: web-services, ios6, passbook, if-modified-since

I add a pass with serial 1 to iPod touch , then I add a pass to iPhone 5 with serial 34455. Next, I push a new pass; now I just can update pass by toggling the back of pass. I toggle the pass in iPhone 5, then pass is updated. But when I toggle the pass in iPod touch, pass cannot be updated and I get this error in php_error.log:
 `[01-May-2013 10:51:56 Europe/Berlin] Passbook Error Log: [2013-05-01 15:51:54 +0700] Get pass task (pass type pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest, serial number 1, if-modified-since Wed, 01 May 2013 14:59:39 GMT + 7; with web service url http://192.168.1.202/passesWebserver/webService/) encountered error: Requested serial number 1, received serial number 34455`
 
What should I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web service code is serving up the wrong pass in response to the `Get Latest Version of a Pass` call.  The iPos is requesting serial number 1 (the same serial as the installed pass), but your web service is responding with serial 34455.

Check your code that services the `Get Latest Version of a Pass` call.  You are serving a .pkpass bundle for serial 34455 when you should be serving the bundle for serial 1.

Comment: so do I need to have different if-modified-since for different pass ?

Comment: You don't set the `If-Modified-Since` header, you receive it.  You set the `Last-Modified` header, and yes, the header that you serve with each pass needs to match the time that is was last modified.  Equally, the `lastUpdated` tag that you send with the serials needs to be relevant to the device that you are sending to.  headers are not causing your problem here though - your problem is with the logic you are using to decide which .pkpass bundle to serve to which device.

Comment: I got similar error even though I passed correct bundle, " encountered error: Requested serial number 1, received serial number 1" while pulling to refresh pass. The top text changed to "Could not update". Please help.